# Excel VBA - Dictionary - storing and retrieving values

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, mapping, storing-information

I am working on below table and with help of Excel VBA - Dictionary - I am trying to capture all the details -
1) First step is to search in "Results Out" Column - if the value is "No" - then we need to read all the values with their appropriate header.
2) So for 2nd record - i.e., Name = XYZ - we need to store all the details. Based on No. of Subjects column - we need to store value of all the subjects and their corresponding marks - will be used for further calculation and generate the "Result" column.

I got it partially working - like I am able to capture details - but not able to store details of all the subject and their marks:

```
Sr. No. Results Out?    Result  Name    Age No. of Subjects Subject Names   Marks
1           Yes          Pass   ABC      21       3          Maths           10
                                                             Science         26
                                                             History         34
2           No                  XYZ      10       2          Maths           24
                                                             Science         36
```

Below is the code that I have used that is partially working:

```
Public Sub test_dict()

Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary
Set dict = New dictionary

sSheetIndex = 1
intTargetRow = 2

Set objUsedRange = Worksheets.Item(3).UsedRange

For Iter = 1 To objUsedRange.Columns.Count
   sCellName = objUsedRange.Cells(1, Iter)
   sCellValue = objUsedRange.Cells(intTargetRow, Iter)
   dict.Item(sCellName) = sCellValue

Next


For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    s = dict.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print dict.Keys()(i) & " " & dict.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print s
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? And why do you need a dictionary? It appears that you might get all you need with just worksheet formulas.

Comment: @RachelHettinger - Actually I am using dictionary as there will be large no. of records (around 14000) - and I will have to process them and use it as input for another functions and it will be much more complicated, so using dictionary, rather than worksheet formulas.

My question - is that when I am using about dictionary code, I am able to store key-value mapping for all the fields, except subject and marks mapping. I might have to use another dictionary specially for subject and marks - but dont know how to correlate it with 1st dictionary.

Comment: So you are using the dictionary object because that's what you need to pass to the other functions, right? If so, then look to those other functions to see how the subjects/marks data is to be passed in.

Comment: The dictionary's `Items` need not be string, They could be a variant array or a collection to hold several items for each key, you could even create a custom data structure (a Class Object) with named properties/etc., instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue with below code - had to use 2 seperate dictionaries:

```
Public Sub test_dict()

Dim dict As New Scripting.dictionary
Set dict = New dictionary

sSheetIndex = 1
intTargetRow = 2

Set objUsedRange = Worksheets.Item(3).UsedRange

For Iter = 1 To objUsedRange.Columns.Count
   sCellName = objUsedRange.Cells(1, Iter)
   sCellValue = objUsedRange.Cells(intTargetRow, Iter)
   dict.Item(sCellName) = sCellValue

    If sCellName = "Subject Names" Then
        Call test_dict_2
    End If

Next

For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    s = dict.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print dict.Keys()(i) & " " & dict.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print s
Next i

End Sub



Public Sub test_dict_2()

Dim dict_2 As New Scripting.dictionary
Set dict_2 = New dictionary

sSheetIndex = 1
intTargetRow = row_counter

Set objUsedRange = Worksheets.Item(3).UsedRange

For Iter = 1 To objUsedRange.Columns.Count
   sHeader = objUsedRange.Cells(1, Iter)
   sCellValue = objUsedRange.Cells(intTargetRow, Iter)

    If sHeader = "No. of Subjects" Then
        mv_cnt = sCellValue
    End If

    If sHeader = "Subject Names" Then

        Dim a
        a = Iter + mv_cnt
        For Iter_2 = Iter To (a - 1)

            sHeader = objUsedRange.Cells(1, Iter)
            sCellName = objUsedRange.Cells(intTargetRow, Iter)
            sCellValue = objUsedRange.Cells(intTargetRow, Iter + 1)
            dict_2.Item(sCellName) = sCellValue
            intTargetRow = intTargetRow + 1

        Next

        intTargetRow = row_counter

    End If

Next

For i = 0 To dict_2.Count - 1
    s = dict_2.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print dict_2.Keys()(i) & " " & dict_2.Items()(i)
    Debug.Print s
Next i

Set dict_2 = Nothing

End Sub
```