# Why can't I reference another dictionary from inside a foreach loop? VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, foreach

```
    Debug.Print distdic(1813)
For Each Key In storedic.Keys
     NewBook.Sheets("Store Bulletin List").Cells(x, 1).Value = Key
     NewBook.Sheets("Store Bulletin List").Cells(x, 2).Value = distdic(Key)
     Debug.Print distdic(Key)
    x = x + 1
Next
```

The first debug produces a result
but that second debug does not even if the Key is 1813

Why can't I use my distdic from inside the foreach loop?

Comment: is `distdic` defined in the code before the loop? And isn't the syntax something like `distdic.Items(key)`?

Comment: yes, and it's a fully loaded dictionary. Values are in there for sure.

Comment: first debug works... second debug doesn't

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987411/excel-vba-dictionary-storing-and-retrieving-values) for correct syntax

Comment: It's like the dictionary loses scope simply because it's outside of the foreach. Which makes no sense to me.

Comment: its your syntax, see my previous comment

Comment: If you're talking about dict.Keys()(i)  It's not that I am referencing the value instead of the key. It's something else. like I said my first debug works. Also if you're talking about dict.Items(Key) that causes a missing object error. So I am not sure what you are pointing me to. ?

Comment: what is the error you get? or what happens?

Comment: project let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not get an object <<--- error I get.  However, as setup in the OP it doesn't error, just doesn't pull a value at all.

Comment: try `distdic.Keys()(Key)` I just tested it and it worked. [This](http://www.attention-to-details.com/newslog/37k-vba-error-property-let-procedure-not.asp) helped.

Comment: produces a script out of range error

Comment: are you sure you loaded the items and keys in the proper way in both dictionaries?

Comment: fixed.. provided answer here for posterity. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Debug.Print distdic(1813)
For Each Key In storedic.Keys
     NewBook.Sheets("Store Bulletin List").Cells(x, 1).Value = Key
     NewBook.Sheets("Store Bulletin List").Cells(x, 2).Value = distdic(Cint(Key))
     Debug.Print distdic(Cint(Key))
    x = x + 1
Next
```

Problem was the datatype of the Key. The above fixed it.